# About lists:suffix/2 in Erlang

Tags: list, erlang

The source code:

```
suffix(Suffix, List) ->
    Delta = length(List) - length(Suffix),
    Delta >= 0 andalso nthtail(Delta, List) =:= Suffix.
```

How about rewriting it like the follow:

```
suffix(Suffix, List) ->
    prefix(reverse(Suffix), reverse(List)).
```

If Delta >=0, the first one will traverse four times, and the second one will traverse three times, is it correct?

Comment: Turned my previous comment into an answer and added some details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one (from stdlib lists.erl) will traverse both lists twice each, yes. On the other hand, on the second traversal all the list cells will probably be in L2 cache, and it doesn't have to allocate any data. Your suggestion works too, but has to build two reversed temporary lists on the heap, which both has a cost in allocating and initializing data structures as well as causing garbage collection to happen more often on average.

If you think about the same problem in C (or any similar language): testing whether one singly linked list is a suffix of another singly linked list, it becomes more obvious why it's hard to do efficiently, in particular if you want to avoid allocating memory, and you aren't allowed to use tricks like reversing pointers.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it is correct. As far as I know, length is a build in function which does not need to traverse the list to get the result (it is the reason why it is allowed in guard test), and the andalso is a kind of shortcut. if the first term is false, it does not evaluate the second term and directly return false.

Comment: length(L) always traverses L. Don't use it in a guard if you can avoid it.